# How to Remove tabs in specific page in ionic2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-tabs

I am new to ionic2, I want to remove tabs from specific page.
I am using below code :

```
import { NavController, App } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public app: App){

this.navCtrl.push(MainPage);
}
```

but whenever using above code all pages tabs are removed.
I want to remove specific page only.
Please help me....

Answer (score 5):

You can hide tabs on sub pages of a tab by using the `tabsHideOnSubPages` attribute:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Contacts" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="information-circle" tabsHideOnSubPages="true"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

This will not show tabs for sub pages within **this** tab.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can just add “tabsHideOnSubPages: true” to your app.module.ts config

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{ tabsHideOnSubPages: true })
```